# Is reserved capacity option still available?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm used to seeing it in the bigquery pricing docs, but now it's just not there:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Did something change in bigquery policy and they don't offer reserved capacity anymore? :O

Answer (score 3):

Reserved BigQuery capacity is no longer an officially advertised option. That said, if you've got a workload that would fit with reserved capacity in some form, or you are doing a lot of queries and are interested in other pricing options, contact google cloud sales (https://cloud.google.com/contact/) or a cloud support representative, and they may be able to help.

Comment: This is definitely a game changer for a company in early stages (such as the one I'm working in) that planned to use BigQuery as data warehouse. We're supposed to serve other businesses and our scaling must not be limited. For example living with 20 concurrent queries limit is just not possible. I'd really appreciate more information.

Comment: "may be able to help" is not something we can count on. We have to know the pricing details. I have to admit this sharp change of policy caught us completely off guard and might force us to dismiss the idea of using bigquery (and Google cloud) all together. Really really disappointing. I believe we're not the only company to be serverly harmed by that.

Comment: How did such a change just went under the radar? It's not even in changes log! Please elaborate what is the consideration behind the change? Is Google against people using bigquery as data warehouse? And if not, how can we count on scaling endlessly when 20 concurrent queries seems like a serious bottleneck?

Comment: Google does want people to use BigQuery as a data warehouse. For the time being, we would just like to have a relationship with the folks who are doing so, in order to better understand their needs and craft a custom capacity solution. The official docs are in flux, and I'd expect things to get easier fairly soon.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I'll contact sales hoping to craft such custom solution which will fit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested to understand your use cases in more detail as well. shaylevi2, when you contact sales can you request a connection to the BQ Product Management team?

Comment: Alright, I sent the sales representative the request, hopefully she will respond to it soon. Thanks.